# Calculating the intersection of two histograms as percentage

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn, histogram

I have two sets of data:

Dataset 1:

```
-4.96600134256044 
-4.78340374913002
-4.93136896680689
-4.80958108060998
-4.78688287192542
-4.9431452930913
-4.93676628405869
-4.87328189586985
-4.91867843591513
-4.72101863119006
-4.95749167305945
-4.79202404641664
-4.91265785779198
-4.94596580589554
-4.96595222256787
-4.7990191635208
-4.97194852291884
-4.78515347272161
-4.78340374913002
-4.8994168374135
-4.97206198058066
-4.95252689510477
-4.93963055552644
-4.95490836707013
-4.94133564424905
-4.78567577865158
-4.93963055552644
-4.93131563559386
-4.9710618452962
-4.90015209439797
-4.9665194453887
-4.93403567225855
-4.91165041153205
-4.85009602823937
-4.78340374913002
-4.77292978439906
-4.94782851444531
-4.64848347534667
-4.91165041153205
-4.82937702765807
-4.96202809430577
-4.7983814963622
-4.93198889539142
-4.97072129594592
-4.88775205449138
-4.96917754667146
-4.972240408012
-4.96062137229138
-4.84390165131993
-4.93630849353535
-4.92623245728544
-4.91859094033325
-4.89568644535618
-4.87243553740634
-4.76982873302833
-4.8953404941385
-4.94451830002783
-4.88104841757604
-4.80303414573805
-4.88705883246573
-4.96499558513462
-4.56610914869673
-4.96928985131163
-4.80780803677881
-4.9556234540787
-4.84808934356167
-4.72319662154655
-4.9575854510567
-4.96960730728536
-4.9056755790436
-4.94039653820335
-4.53920246550341
-4.97211181130125
-4.86213634700864
-4.96802952189005
-4.9717135485154
-4.82056508210921
-4.96777645971916
-4.94038569046493
-4.95173085290477
-4.83470303172871
-4.91551379314551
-4.93963055552644
-4.97211181086369
-4.807583383435
-4.97216236251657
-4.97232745985347
-4.91551379314551
-4.94522084426514
-4.89719997383376
-4.96071975048121
-4.93464863469402
-4.88775205449138
-4.91638381844513
-4.80256598250479
-4.79828215315771
-4.73688107699373
-4.88114134915641
-4.92310502488463
```

Dataset 2:

```
-4.96600134256044
-4.78340374913002
-4.93136896680689
-4.80958108060998
-4.78688287192542
-4.9431452930913
-4.93676628405869
-4.87328189586985
-4.91867843591513
-4.72101863119006
-4.95749167305945
-4.79202404641664
-4.91265785779198
-4.94596580589554
-4.96595222256787
-4.7990191635208
-4.97194852291884
-4.78515347272161
-4.78340374913002
-4.8994168374135
-4.97206198058066
-4.95252689510477
-4.93963055552644
-4.95490836707013
-4.94133564424905
-4.78567577865158
-4.93963055552644
-4.93131563559386
-4.9710618452962
-4.90015209439797
-4.9665194453887
-4.93403567225855
-4.91165041153205
-4.85009602823937
-4.78340374913002
-4.77292978439906
-4.94782851444531
-4.64848347534667
-4.91165041153205
-4.82937702765807
-4.96202809430577
-4.7983814963622
-4.93198889539142
-4.97072129594592
-4.88775205449138
-4.96917754667146
-4.972240408012
-4.96062137229138
-4.84390165131993
-4.93630849353535
-4.92623245728544
-4.91859094033325
-4.89568644535618
-4.87243553740634
-4.76982873302833
-4.8953404941385
-4.94451830002783
-4.88104841757604
-4.80303414573805
-4.88705883246573
-4.96499558513462
-4.56610914869673
-4.96928985131163
-4.80780803677881
-4.9556234540787
-4.84808934356167
-4.72319662154655
-4.9575854510567
-4.96960730728536
-4.9056755790436
-4.94039653820335
-4.53920246550341
-4.97211181130125
-4.86213634700864
-4.96802952189005
-4.9717135485154
-4.82056508210921
-4.96777645971916
-4.94038569046493
-4.95173085290477
-4.83470303172871
-4.91551379314551
-4.93963055552644
-4.97211181086369
-4.807583383435
-4.97216236251657
-4.97232745985347
-4.91551379314551
-4.94522084426514
-4.89719997383376
-4.96071975048121
-4.93464863469402
-4.88775205449138
-4.91638381844513
-4.80256598250479
-4.79828215315771
-4.73688107699373
-4.88114134915641
-4.92310502488463
```

And I'm trying to plot them as histograms and then measure the overlap between the histograms as a percentage of the total area of the histograms. I tried using the method [suggested in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72931022/how-to-calculate-histogram-intersection), but that gave me an answer larger than 1--which I didn't think would be possible.

My code looks like this:

```
rng = min(dataset1.min(),dataset2.min()),max(dataset1.max(),dataset2.max())
n1, bins1,_= plt.hist(dataset1,color = color1,alpha = 0.75,bins=7,weights =(np.ones_like(dataset1)/len(dataset1)),range=rng)
n1_area = sum(np.diff(bins1)*n1)
n2, bins2,_ = plt.hist(dataset2,color = color2,alpha = 0.75,bins = 7,weights =(np.ones_like(dataset2)/len(dataset2)),range=rng)
n2_area = sum(np.diff(bins2)*n2)
overlap = np.minimum(n1,n2)
overlap_area = overlap.sum()
overlap_percentage=overlap_area/(n1_area+n2_area)
```

Anyone have any idea why I'm getting a percentage that's over 1, and how to fix it so that I get the correct value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you calc the real "area" of the hist figure for n1 and n2 by `n1_area=sum(np.diff(bins1)*n1)`. But the `overlap` is just the count for samples. They are practically incomparable.
You can use both count for samples, i.e. `overlap.sum()`, or use both "area", i.e. `sum(np.diff(bins1)*n1)`. But not to mix them.
To be more clear, the last percentage should be calculated as `overlap / (n1 + n2 - overlap)`. Since the total area of n1 and n2 with an overlap is `(n1 + n2 - overlap)`. [Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hG3xT.png)

Answer (score 1):

- Some of the code will be similar to [How to plot the difference between two histograms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76264602/7758804), except `density` will be used in [`np.histogram`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html).

  - In order to calculate the overlap, the bin edges of the two histograms must be the same.
- `np.histogram`

  - > density : bool, optional
    > If `False`, the result will contain the number of samples in
    > each bin. If `True`, the result is the value of the
    > probability *density* function at the bin, normalized such that
    > the *integral* over the range is 1. Note that the sum of the
    > histogram values will not be equal to 1 unless bins of unity
    > width are chosen; it is not a probability *mass* function.
  - In this case, the bin widths are `0.5`, so `h1` and `h2` need to be multiplied by `0.5`.
- Custom normal samples are used, because the two datasets in the OP are exactly the same.
- **Tested in `python 3.11.3`, `pandas 2.0.2`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`, `seaborn 0.12.2`, `numpy 1.24.3`**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# sample datasets
np.random.seed(2023)
dataset1 = np.random.normal(loc=9, scale=1.5, size=100)
dataset2 = np.random.normal(loc=8, scale=0.6, size=100)

# create a long form dataframe for use with seaborn
df = pd.DataFrame({'ds1': dataset1, 'ds2': dataset2}).melt()

# calculate the density hist for each dataset with specified matching bin edges
h1, be1 = np.histogram(dataset1, bins=np.arange(4, 13.1, 0.5), density=True)
h2, be2 = np.histogram(dataset2, bins=np.arange(4, 13.1, 0.5), density=True)
```

- Plot the two datasets with [`sns.histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html) to see where there are overlapping bins.

  - See [How to add value labels on a bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804) for a thorough explanation of using `.bar_label`.
- The bar annotations match the values for `h1 * 0.5` and `h2 * 0.5`

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
ax = sns.histplot(data=df, x='value', stat='density', hue='variable', multiple='dodge', bins=np.arange(4, 13.1, 0.5))
ax.set_xticks(be2)

ax.margins(x=0)

for c in ax.containers:
    _ = ax.bar_label(c, fontsize=8)
```

[image]

- Calculate the overlapping percent by creating a [`logical_and`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) map for the Booleans, where `h1` and `h2` are not equal to 0.

```py
# create a mask for where each data set is non-zero
m1 = h1 != 0
m2 = h2 != 0

# use a logical and to create a combined map where both datasets are non-zero
ol = np.logical_and(m1, m2)

# calculate the overlapping density, where 0.5 is the bin width
ol_density = np.abs((h1 - h2) * 0.5)[ol]

# calculate the total overlap percent
ol_perecent = ol_density.sum() * 100

ol_perecent → 71.00000000000001
```

- Plot the absolute value of the overlapping areas with [`sns.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html).
- Comparing the next plot to the previous plot shows bars from the bins of the overlapping data.
- The sum of the bar value annotations is equal to `ol_percent`.

```py
# calculate the absolute difference for each bin
y = np.abs(h1 - h2) * 0.5

# set non-overlapping bins to 0
y[~ol] = 0

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
ax = sns.barplot(y=y, x=be1[:-1], width=1, ec='k', color='purple', alpha=0.75)
_ = ax.set_xticks(ticks=np.arange(0, 18, 1)-0.5, labels=be1[:-1])

ax.margins(x=0, y=0.1)

for c in ax.containers:
    _ = ax.bar_label(c, fontsize=8, padding=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't this imply that the overlap of a histogram with itself is 0?